# Returning a function in C#

Tags: c#, first-class

I have this snippet

```
private void westButton_click(object sender, EventArgs ea)
{
    PlayerCharacter.Go(Direction.West);
}
```

repeated for North, South and East.

How can I declare a function that'd let me generate methods like ir programmatically?

e.g., I'd like to be able to call

```
northButton.Click += GoMethod(Direction.North);
```

instead of defining the method, and then

```
northButton.Click += new EventHandler(northButton.Click);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
northButton.Click += (s, e) => GoMethod(Direction.North);
```

(or...)

```
northButton.Click += (s, e) => PlayerCharacter.Go(Direction.North);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
northButton.Click += (s,e) => GoMethod(Direction.North);
```

Comment: () => PlayerCharacter.Go(Direction.North)

Comment: How are you adding a lambda expression that takes no parameters to an event as a handler that expects a delegate that takes two parameters: object and EventArgs? It should be (s,e) => PlayerCharacter.Go(Direction.North) or delegate { PlayerCharacter.Go(Direction.North);}

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a solution:

```
private EventHandler GoMethod(Direction dir)
{
    return new EventHandler((object sender, EventArgs ea) => PlayerCharacter.Go(dir));
}
```

My only concern would be about binding time; if PlayerCharacter is `null` when I call GoMethod, what would happen?

Comment: The PlayerCharacter and dir variables are captured (closed over) with a closure.  The compiler will generate extra code behind the scenes to "hoist" them into a their own private class and instance so they retain their state at the time this code ran.